# Tension in string and Spring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why is that a massless string has same tension throughout its length provided the string is inextensible. Similarly in spring block problems we take spring as massless as well and here too we consider spring force to be uniform throughout it's natural length.
I actually want the derivation of how do we get this.
Thank you.

Comment: Your second question is not clear. Please clarify it.

Comment: now is it fine?

Comment: So the two questions are connected.

Comment: The logical explanation is indeed the derivation.

Comment: Tang's answer is just the mathematical way of representing the logical explanation

Comment: @Atharav if you applied two forces at one end and the other end of the rope, you get the equation $F_2-F_1=k\,\Delta L$ (spring equation) where $L$ is the rope length. but if the rope length is unchanged then $F_1$ must be equal $F_2$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider points $A$ and $B$ on the string, which has tension $F_A$ and $F_B$, respectively. We can consider part of the string, $AB$ and apply the Newton's law of motion on this system. We then obtain

$$F_A - F_B = ma$$

However, since $m$ is zero, it forces $F_A = F_B$ unless $a\rightarrow\infty$, which is not physical.

Comment: So this happens at every point on string hence we take tension as uniform?

Comment: Also what about spring then?

Comment: It means the force pulling that segment of the string forward will be the equal to the force pulling backward, which is the condition that we need (otherwise you get the infinite acceleration). The spring is basically not different from the string.